# Dbcontextoptions unable to understand

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, radix

I didn't understand this statement why using " : " colon sign is it inheriting base function or some thing else. I get confused on ":base(option) {}" it doesn't make sense

public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
: base(options) {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to explain what is happening, first I'm going to make a few assumptions:

**1)** The class in which your constructor code

`public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {}`

resides in is called "*ApplicationDbContext*".

**2)** ApplicationDbContext inherits directly from the "*DbContext*" class. Which makes DbContext the **base** class of ApplicationDbContext.

"**: base**" means '*call the constructor of the base class when the constructor of ApplicationDbContext is called.*'

"***: base(options)***" means '*call the constructor of the base class using the passed parameter of the type DbContextOptions called "options", when the constructor of ApplicationDbContext is called*.'

The "**:**" symbol is part of the C# syntax to specify the calling of a base method.